# C# ChromimunFX: How to create multiTab browsing, and isolate between each tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, chromium-embedded

I’m trying to use an embedded browser into my WinForms application. I used CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser, it work perfectly. However, CEFSharp requires the Visual C++ 2013, or the Visual C++ 2008….I think it is a complicated dependency.  I'm creating a portable application without the dependency envirenment.

I have found another library, similar CefSharp, also use Chrominum, called ChromiumFX (visit: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx ). The library uses the .Net Framework 3.5 (Default available in Windows 7) , no need to install Visual C++. And it is  suitable for my application.

But I don’t find any way to create multi tabs application with this library. Here is what I tried to do:

```
private void LifeSpanHandler_OnBeforePopup(object sender, CfxOnBeforePopupEventArgs e)
 {
     e.SetReturnValue(true);
     tabPage2.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() =>
     {
         ChromiumWebBrowser b = new ChromiumWebBrowser(e.TargetUrl);
         b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
         tabPage2.Controls.Add(b);
     });
}
```

InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired is an extension method:

```
public static void InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
 {
     if (control.InvokeRequired)
     {
         control.BeginInvoke(action);
     }
     else
     {
         action.Invoke();
     }
}
```

But the application error and the program has crashed.

Another thing, when I created a new instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, I want it isolated with another instance, it means do not use the same cookies, sessions with any instance (private browser). In CefSharp, just create a new RequestContext for new instance:

```
webbrowser.RequestContext = new RequestContext();
```

But in ChromiumFX, I dont find any way to do that!

Somebody help me? Thank for you help!

Comment: In regards to `VC++` You don't need to install it on every computer, you can package it with your app. There are a few options for this, the `FAQ` contains more information. A new option that I've just become aware of is use a `Nuget` package from `Jetbrains`, should be a simple matter of install and it'll copy the dependencies for you. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VC120.CRT.JetBrains/

Comment: `RequestContext` maps to `CefRequestContext`, it's passed to `CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser`. I'm sure if you dig through the source you'll find how it maps. http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefBrowserHost.html#CreateBrowser%28constCefWindowInfo&,CefRefPtr%3CCefClient%3E,constCefString&,constCefBrowserSettings&,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequestContext%3E%29

Comment: Looks like if you use the `JetBrains` package you still need to manually copy the files to your executing folder. Just copy the three dll's, it's a trivial task.

Comment: Thank @amaitland, it work perfectly. When I use the Google Chrome browser, and see in taskmanager, there are processes  called Google Chrome was created. Similarly, when I run the program using the ChromiumFX library, there are processes have same name with the program was created. But when I run the program using the CefSharp library, 1 process of the program was created, and many processes named CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe was created. Why CefSharp not designed to create multiple processes of the program with the same name as Google Chrome or ChromiumFX?

Comment: In the context of an open source project I don't see that `why not` questions are productive. Is it possible? Yes. Are you prepared to contribute to the project? If this is a feature you require then you'll need to contribute.....